# 301 redirect phpbb2 to xenforo

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Could someone please help me with my .htaccess settings? I need to redirect my old forum urls (phpbb2) to new xenforo urls.

Example
Old:

```
 www.myforum.de/ftopic7469.html
```

New:

```
 www.myforum.de/threads/werbelinks-hier-im-forum.7469/
```

Same with Forums:

Old:

```
 www.myforum.de/forum61.html
```

New:

```
 www.myforum.de/forums/wuensche-und-feedback.61/
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Are you using apache as your web server?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yes i do.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^ftopic([0-9]+)\.html$  /threads/$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^forum([0-9]+)\.html$  /forums/$1 [R,L]
```

Note that it doesn't take care of slug, but, as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34473844/nginx-redirect-rewrite-vbulletin-urls-with-slug-to-xenforo-slug-optional/38166902#38166902, the slug part isn't actually mandatory, so, we don't have to worry about it.